# how to add above each column a different pie chart

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, pie-chart

i have a column chart for male distribution of my data .
my question if it's possible to add on the same chart , above each column a pie chart to display other data (such as cities ) for each male ?

EDIT : 
i saw this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo
on thier demo and that what gave me the idea. but in the code they display the pie chart by saying specificly where to put it not based on the x-axis . any help if it is possible ? because the pie chart doesn't have a x y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on each column and then add pie serie

```
 var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];


    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, data) {
        console.log(data);
        chart.addSeries({
            type: 'pie',
            data: [{
                y: 13
            }, {
                y: 23
            }, {
                y: 19
            }],
            center: [xAxis.toPixels(data.x, true) - 20, yAxis.toPixels(data.y, true) - 50],
            size: 50,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        })
    });
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f6rnr17c/